# Python overwrite sys.excepthook on project level

Tags: python

I have a simple logging function `log_exception`. 
I want to overwrite `sys.excepthook` so that exception thrown in any project module will be nicely logged.

Now I'm seeing two solutions:

1. use site packages- but that is user specific configuration and I want to change whole project behauviour
2. write `sys.excepthook = log_exception` in every module.

Second solution will work of course, but it is not elegant. Is there some better way to to it?

Comment: Neither of those options make sense. You only need to set `sys.excepthook` once in a program, ideally at startup. You don't need to do it in every module, and site-packages is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: second version is more elegant. But I expect that if you do it in main script then it will use it in all imported script and they don't need it manually added. (PL: druga wersja jest bardziej elegancka. Ale spodziewam się, że jak użyjesz tego w głownym skrypcie to będzie to wykorzystane we wszystkich zaimportowanych plikach i nie ma potrzeby tego dodawać ręcznie do pozostałych)

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry, I though it will not work on multiple modules since I've been trying it on async functions.